# Same out put for different sort criteria in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying out the below code but not sure why I am getting the same output for output 1 and output 2.

```
var nameArray = [{name : "Arindam",age: 26},{name: "Sumit",age:22},{name: "Arnab",age:35},{name: "Rajdeep",age:30}];

nameArray.sort(function(v1,v2){
    if(v1.name > v2.name){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
});

console.dir(nameArray);//Output 1

nameArray.sort(function(v1,v2){
    if(v1.age < v2.age){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
});

console.log("--------------");
console.dir(nameArray);//output 2
```

output 1 and 2 are same as below :

```
Array[4]
    0: Object
        age: 22
        name: "Sumit"
        __proto__: Object
    1: Object
        age: 26
        name: "Arindam"
        __proto__: Object
    2: Object
        age: 30
        name: "Rajdeep"
        __proto__: Object
    3: Object
        age: 35
        name: "Arnab"
```

Is it both the sort functions are getting executed before printing to console?Can anyone please explain in details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: Yey, try `console.dir(nameArray.slice());`

Comment: i get different output on edge, but your conparison does not look for same values.

Comment: Btw, what is expected output of first sorting?

Comment: @sinisake      
{
    "name": "Sumit",
    "age": 22
  },
  {
    "name": "Rajdeep",
    "age": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Arnab",
    "age": 35
  },
  {
    "name": "Arindam",
    "age": 26
  }

Answer (score 1):

Both of your console log are using the same variable `nameArray` which seems to point to the same memory address, or due to the browser console.

In order to solve this, you can clone your object into another variable:

```js
var nameArray = [{
    name: "Arindam",
    age: 26
}, {
    name: "Sumit",
    age: 22
}, {
    name: "Arnab",
    age: 35
}, {
    name: "Rajdeep",
    age: 30
}];

nameArray.sort(function(v1, v2) {
    if (v1.name > v2.name) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});

console.dir(nameArray); //Output 1

//Clone nameArray into nameArray2
nameArray2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nameArray));

nameArray2.sort(function(v1, v2) {
    if (v1.age < v2.age) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});

console.log("--------------");
console.dir(nameArray2); //output 2
```

Comment: Yes, the problem may be with the browser console. I just ran my original code replacing the console.dir(nameArray) with alert(JSON.stringify(nameArray)) and I am getting the desired output without cloning the old array into a new array.